# Trouble updating a Mongoose Array entry

Tags: arrays, mongoose, element

I'm trying to update a document with an array of objects.

If the device object exists I want to replace the token value.  If it doesn't exist, push a new `device/token` pair onto the array.

I have tried several approaches to getting a match in the query and positional set options.

For some reason if the device already exists, I can't get the value of the token modified.

```
const fcmSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
  fcmtoken: String,
  device: String,
});

const dbuserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  fcm: [fcmSchema],

})

const fcm = {
    fcmtoken: fcmtoken,
    device: device
}

dbUsers.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email, 'fcm': { $elemMatch : { 'device': 'web' }}}, { $set: {'fcm.$.device': 'worked', 'fcm.$.fcmtoken': 'worked'}},  {'new': true},  (err, doc) => {
    console.log('DOC:', doc);
    console.log('ERROR:', err);

if (!doc) {
          return dbUsers
          .findOneAndUpdate({ 'email': email }, {$push: { "fcm": fcm}}, {'new': true},  (err, doc) => {
            console.log('DOC1:', doc);
            console.log('ERROR1:', err);
        }
```

The result I would expect is on the first pass with no values in the array, the second `findOneAndUpdate` would push an initial value on the array.

At some point when the token changes, the first `findOneAndUpdate` would match and change the device and token value to `worked` (used for debugging only).

I have tried several variations of the first query and can't get a match.

Answer (score 0):

I finally narrowed this one down to another function stepping on the DB entry. The code was fine, just a previous call that overwrote the fcm array.   Thanks!